# Inequality bewteen integral of a squared function and the square of the integrated function

Tags: integration, inequality

**Situation** I am intrigued by this inequality

$ a \int_0^a f^2 dx \ne \left( \int_0^a f dx \right)^2 $

where $f=f(x)$ is some vanilla real function of reals, continuous and admitting continuous first and second derivatives, at least. 
It can have any sign. 
Obviously, $f$ is not a constant. 
Also, both integrals exist and are finite.

**Question (still unanswered)** Are there ways to express $ \int_0^a f^2 dx $ as an approximation of $ \int_0^a f dx $? Which ones?

**Aim (addressed by [Chappers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2279210/446004) below)** The ultimate aim would be to anticipate how large the difference

$ a \int_0^a f^2 dx -\left( \int_0^a f dx \right)^2 $

is for different choices of $f$.

**Note** To gauge the lingo in the answers, I am no mathematician by training (clearly), but I would also welcome being pointed out to expositions for educators if you know any

Comment: if $f=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ and $a=1$, then the difference will go to infinity, perhaps, you're asking for when $f$ is square integrable too

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Thanks. Question edited: I assume that both integrals exist and are finite.

Answer (score 5):

We have $(f(x)-f(y))^2 \geq 0$ for any $x$ and $y$ where $f$ is defined, and moreover, this continuous, and zero if and only if $f$ is constant.

Then we state the identity
$$ 0 \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^a\int_0^a (f(x)-f(y))^2 \, dx \, dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^a \int_0^a (f(x)^2 - 2f(x)f(y)+f(y)^2) \, dx \, dy \\
= a\int_0^a f^2 - \left( \int_0^a f \right)^2 $$
by expanding the double integral.

To estimate the difference more precisely, one can try to produce an upper bound $$J[f]=\int_0^a\int_0^a (f(x)-f(y))^2 \, dx \, dy.$$

A trivial bound may be found by noting that $$(f(x)-f(y))^2 \leq (M-m)^2,$$ where $M$ and $m$ are the maximum and minimum values $f$ takes on in the interval, and it follows that
$$J[f] \leq a^2 (M-m)^2.$$

Alternatively, since $f$ is differentiable, the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says that
 $$f(x)-f(y) = (x-y)f'(z)$$ 
for some $z$ strictly between $x$ and $y$, which gives the bound for the integrand
$$(f(x)-f(y))^2 \leq (x-y)^2 (\max_{(0,a)}{f'})^2,$$ 
and then the bound for the integral
$$ J[f] \leq (\max_{(0,a)}{f'})^2 \int_0^a\int_0^a (x-y)^2 \, dx\, dy = \frac{a^4}{6} \left(\max_{(0,a)}{f'}\right)^2 $$

This is probably the most than can be said without more stringent conditions on $f$: one can set up a smooth function with integral zero and integral of its square as large as one likes, for example, and indeed, likely saturate one or both of the bounds I have given; the best one could hope for in bounds of this type is probably to sharpen the constants (there will be bounds on the size of the set where $f$ is close to $M$ versus $m$, for example).

We also have via the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)
$$ J[f] = \int_0^a\int_0^a \left( \int_x^y f'(z) \, dz \right)^2 \, dx \, dy, $$
which may lead to a better bound depending on how much one can say about $f'$.

Comment: The post is really valuable and to the point, hence an upvote, but the question whether one can express $\int_0^a f^2$ as an approximation of $\int_0^a f$ is not addressed (in my eyes).

Comment: Is $J[f]$ meant to represent the double integral (top of answer) or the upper bound (bottom of answer)? Or, if the question is ill-posed: is the last definition of $J[f]$ the same as the first? (Note I have edited the text for readability and it has been peer-reviewed, but I may have well introduced the slip that puzzles me)

Comment: If you calculate the integral in the last displayed equation, you'll see that it is the same as the definition of $J[f]$.

Comment: For integrals like this, it's often helpful to think in terms of sums to start with. How much does $(x+y)^2$ say about $x^2+y^2$? Not much, unless you also have $(x-y)^2$, since $(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2=2(x^2+y^2)$. Equally, $(x+y+z)^2$ says little about $x^2+y^2+z^2$, since $(x+y+z)^2 + (x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-y)^2 = 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$.

Comment: How does the reasoning on polynomials apply to the linkage between  power of integrals and integrals of powers?

Comment: An integral is an extension of the idea of summation (think of the definition $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) (x_k-x_{k-1})$). On the other hand, a sum can be written as an integral of a piecewise-constant function. Hence many results that apply to sums also apply to integrals, and vice versa (linearity, numerous inequalities, summation/integration by parts, and so on). The examples I have given are the simplest two cases of relations between sums of squares and squares of sums, special cases of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58724/discussion-between-xavierstuvw-and-chappers).